# The manifest filter <compatible-screens> is not working correctly for all devices

Tags: android

I am trying to filter my app based on the flag `<compatible-screens>` but the combination is not working fine for all devices. I want my app to be available to all Android phones and not any of the tablets. I am using the filter as:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

But the problem with this filter is in manifest File, it is counting some tabs like Samsung Galaxy Tab(7')  in the device list and excluding some devices like LG Optimus black.

Can anyone have used these filters or the right combination of filters?

Answer (score 1):

> I want my app to be available to all Android phones and not any of the tablets.

What is a phone? What is a tablet?

You seem to think that there is a universal definition of these terms. You are mistaken.

Your `<compatible-screens>` supports `-small`, `-normal`, and `-large` screens in all four densities. This will include devices like the original Samsung Galaxy Tab (which is 7", not 7', unless this is a Spinal Tap-esque reverse Stonehenge thing), as that device is categorized as `-large`.

As to why the "LG Optimus black" is being filtered out, perhaps that is not tied to your `<compatible-screens>` element, but rather something else (e.g., `android:minSdkVersion`).